# "float;#22.0000000000000" Number Returned From CAML Query

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, caml

I'm running a CAML query to retrieve list items. Some of the columns retrieved contain decimal numbers. The problem is the values coming back from the query look like `float;#22.0000000000000`. I just need `22.0`.

I've tried using `ToString()`, `Decimal.Parse`, casting with `(float)`, `(double)`, etc. and they all give me exceptions.

**How can I resolve this? Why is this even happening?**

CAML query (Approved, Pending and Remaining contain decimal numbers):

```
SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();
qry.Query = String.Format(
@"   <Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Person' />
            <Value Type='Integer'>
                <UserID />
            </Value>
        </Eq>
        <Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Year' />
                <Value Type='Choice'>{0}</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Year' />
                <Value Type='Choice'>{1}</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>
    </And>
</Where>", currentYear.ToString(), (currentYear + 1).ToString());
qry.ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='Approved' /><FieldRef Name='Pending' /><FieldRef Name='Remaining' /><FieldRef Name='Year' />";
SPListItemCollection items = leaveEntList.GetItems(qry);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get a string for conversion is to use SPListItem. the `item.GetFormattedValue("ColumnName")`

Go though the mentioned post, it could be work for you.

[How to convert a decimal number field to C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fdef03db-9678-46cf-8ff7-03551f4b8466/how-to-convert-a-decimal-number-field-to-c?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

Comment: Links can break over time. Please add relevant information from the blog.

Comment: @AmalHashim this is not be a relevant info, how?

Comment: You should quote the relevant text from the link you provided, in case the link goes dead someday.

Comment: Amal was absolutely correct in saying this is how SharePoint stores calculated fields internally. The solution, however, is in the link you provided, thanks. `item.GetFormattedValue("Remaining")` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is how SharePoint stores the data internally. You need to use String manipulation for extracting the data.

```
var data = "float;#22.0000000000000";
//Option 1 - Replace float;# with empty string
string result = data.Replace("float;#", string.Empty);
//Now convert to decimal
decimal d = decimal.Parse(result);

//Option 2 - Using index of #
string result = data.SubString(0, data.IndexOf("#"));
//Now convert to decimal
decimal d = decimal.Parse(result);
```

Comment: Amal, why do I not have this problem if I don't use a CAML query and retrieve the item just by iterating through the list items instead?

Comment: CAML query added.

Comment: Are those look up fields or calculated fields?

Comment: Approved and Pending are number fields. Remaining is calculated. Also should point out that I've only been playing with the Remaining field up until now - not checked the output of Approved and Pending. I wonder if it's because it's a calculated field?

Comment: Yes exactly. When you iterate I believe SharePoint does the Job of converting it back to float. While in CAML query we need to do that of properly converting. The same applies to UserField/LookupField etc.

Answer (score 1):

If your field type is `CALCULATED`, it is a known behaviour
to solve this you can use SPFieldCalculated object
example:

```
SPFieldCalculated cf = (SPFieldCalculated)item.Fields["AverageFeedBackRating"];

string cfVal = cf.GetFieldValueForEidit(item["AverageFeedBackRating"]);
```